# Erro localização do persistence

Tags: java, jpa, eclipse, persistência, java-bean

Estou rodando um projeto com GlassFish4 e precisava rodar como uma aplicação java também, mas ao tentar pegar a localização do projeto como descrito a seguir o InputStream retorna null.

Ao retirar o "/" do `"/" + propertiesName + ".properties"` ele popula o InputStream, mas preciso que ele contenha essa string, pois outros projetos estão linkados a esse projeto.

Localização do output projeto: /target/classes

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/" + propertiesName + ".properties");

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(in);

props.put(propertiesName, properties);
```

Comment: você tentou com `./`?

Comment: Ainda não, irei tentar aqui